Azure DevOps REST API: Match Manual Test Case steps to Test Run results?
I would like to create a simple report for manual test results of test cases using REST API:

Test case step description / expected result
Result: pass / fail
Comments, attachments

I use the following query
http://myserver.is.mycompany.net:8080/tfs/MyCollection/LMTest/_apis/test/Runs/192557/Results?api-version=5.1&detailstoinclude=Iterations
(The latest supported API version on our server is 5.1)
The part of the response is below.
My problem is that the actionResults are not in the order of test case steps.
Looking at the comments, I can see that step 6 actionResult goes after step 2, then step 8, then step 4 etc. This is further complicated by the fact that we use shared steps.
Is there a way I could match the test case steps to the corresponding results from the iteration details?
{
"count": 1,
"value": [
    {
        "id": 100000,

        ...

        "iterationDetails": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "outcome": "Failed",
                "errorMessage": "",
                "durationInMs": 171574,
                "actionResults": [
                    {
                        "actionPath": "00000002",
                        "iterationId": 1,
                        "url": "http://myserver.is.mycompany.net:8080/tfs/MyCollection/LMTest/_apis/test/Runs/192557/Results/100000/Iterations/1/ActionResults/00000002",
                        "outcome": "Failed",
                        "errorMessage": "step 1 comment",
                    },
                    {
                        "actionPath": "00000003",
                        "iterationId": 1,
                        "url": "http://myserver.is.mycompany.net:8080/tfs/MyCollection/LMTest/_apis/test/Runs/192557/Results/100000/Iterations/1/ActionResults/00000003",
                        "outcome": "Failed",
                        "errorMessage": "step 2 comment",
                    },
                    {
                        "actionPath": "00000004",
                        "iterationId": 1,
                        "url": "http://myserver.is.mycompany.net:8080/tfs/MyCollection/LMTest/_apis/test/Runs/192557/Results/100000/Iterations/1/ActionResults/00000004",
                        "outcome": "Failed",
                        "errorMessage": "step 6 comment",
                    },
                    {
                        "actionPath": "00000005",
                        "iterationId": 1,
                        "url": "http://myserver.is.mycompany.net:8080/tfs/MyCollection/LMTest/_apis/test/Runs/192557/Results/100000/Iterations/1/ActionResults/00000005",
                        "outcome": "Failed",
                        "errorMessage": "step 8 comment",
                    },
                    {
                        "actionPath": "00000006",
                        "iterationId": 1,
                        "url": "http://myserver.is.mycompany.net:8080/tfs/MyCollection/LMTest/_apis/test/Runs/192557/Results/100000/Iterations/1/ActionResults/00000006",
                        "outcome": "Failed",
                        "errorMessage": "step 4 comment",
                    },
                    
                    ....
        }
    }
]

}

According to Results - List,

actionPath is the path identifier for test step in test case workitem.

It increments in the order in which the steps are added to the test case, not in the order in which the steps actually appear in the test case.
For example, you added the first step "StepA" to the test case. At this time, the actionPath of this step is 00000002. Then you inserted a new step "StepB" before "StepA". At this time, the actionPath of "StepB" is 00000003. The actionPath of "StepA" remains unchanged, which is still 00000002.

In the API response body, the object in actionResults are sorted in ascending order by actionPath.

The actual execution order is to run StepB first, then run StepA.


To add to the answer above, the steps in the Test Case are defined as below in the field "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps".
The internal ids are not the same as step ids appear in the UI.
The ids match the actionPath in test run results: id 1 would match actionPath 00000001, id 2 would match actionPath 00000002 etc.
This is somewhat cumbersome but lets me match the test step result to the actual test step.
<steps id="0" last="9">
<step id="2" type="ValidateStep">
            <P>Select the menu "change PW" </P>
            <P>User has access to change PW menu item </P>
</step>
<step id="3" type="ValidateStep">
            <P>Type in previous pw and new password in selected fields </P>
            <P>User is able to type in pw's </P>
</step>
<compref id="7" ref="16354">
    <step id="6" type="ValidateStep">
                    <SPAN xml:lang="da-dk">do some stuff</SPAN>
                    <SPAN xml:lang="da-dk">NA</SPAN>
    </step>
    <compref id="8" ref="16354">
        <step id="4" type="ValidateStep">
                    <P>Test other stuff.. </P>
                    <P>other stuff tested </P>
        </step>
        <compref id="9" ref="16354">
            <step id="5" type="ActionStep">
                        <P>End of test case </P>
                        <P> </P>
            </step>
        </compref>
    </compref>
</compref>

